# Solving $p^n = x^2+y^2$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime of the form $p = 4k+1$. Prove that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exist integers $x,y$ not divisible by $p$ such that $$p^n = x^2+y^2.$$

This is an extension of Fermat's Two Square Theorem. Can we use that to solve this question?

Answer (score 2):

Can you prove this statement : given $P$ and $Q$ can be written a sum of two squares, their product $PQ$ can be written as sum of two squares? All you need to do is a little manipulation.

If $P = a^2+b^2$ and $Q = c^2+d^2$, then $PQ = (ac-bd)^2 + (ad+bc)^2$.

Now, if $p = a^2 +  b^2$, you can see from this that $p^2 = (a^2-b^2)^2 + (2ab)^2$ From here, you can proceed by induction, knowing that $p^3=p^2 \cdot p$ and $p^n = p^{n-1} \cdot p$ and so on.

Comment: What is $C$ here?

Comment: @user19405892 My apologies that is a $Q$ not a $C$. Anyhow I have edited the question.

Comment: Granted Fermat's 2 square theorem, it suffices to show that a product of sums of 2 squares is again a sum of 2 squares. This is most rapidly shown by writing a^2 + b^2 = (a + ib)(a - ib), where i^2 = -1

Comment: @nguyenquangdo of course it's  true, but I thought it would be better explicitly shown.